# Apache .htaccess RewriteRule and ErrorDocument

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.mp4|\.ttf|\.eot|\.woff)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 404 /e404
ErrorDocument 403 /e404
ErrorDocument 500 /e500
```

And a PHP function which checks to see if the requested URI exists. If the URI exists in the database, it will get the contents and render the page, if not, it will get the 404 error page contents and render the page. *(Everything is OK here)*

The problem is when I use a URI with extensions which are inside the `RewriteCond` part of the `.htaccess` file, something like `example.com/file.css`. In this case, the page gets redirected to `example.com/e404` *(that's what I want)*. The problem here is:

I don't know how to get the "wrong URI" used before redirecting to `example.com/e404`, because when the error page is loaded, I have a function inside the page to insert the "wrong URI" in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Aside:* The directives you've posted would create a rewrite loop on any default Apache installation, so maybe you have other directives or a different config that you aren't disclosing in your question? Anyway, ignoring this for the moment, since you don't appear to be having a problem like this.

> I don't know how to get the wrong URI used before redirecting to `example.com/e404` ...

But do you need to get this information *before* "redirecting"? In PHP you can simply check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` superglobal to get this information (the URL that resulted in the 404). However, note that this contains the slash prefix and query string (if any), which your `page` URL parameter would not otherwise contain.

Also, just to clarify terminology, this is not strictly a "redirect" to `example.com/e404`. A "redirect" implies an external HTTP redirect. Apache issues an *internal subrequest* for the error document (which is similar to a URL rewrite, but not quite).

One of the potential issues with your code is that the 404 response is served in a rather round-about way:

1. If `file.css` does not exist then Apache triggers an internal subrequest for `/e404`
   (this triggers another round of processing...)
2. Since `/e404` does not end in one of the stated file extensions, it is further rewritten to `?page=e404` (presumably `index.php`?).

Because of the (unnecessary) 2nd rewrite, other server variables, such as `REDIRECT_URL` and `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` (which are also passed through to the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal) are not set as expected. Ordinarily, these would be set to the "wrong URI" (ie. the requested URL that triggered the 404), but instead, they contain details of the error document itself.

You should do the above in 1 step and avoid the second rewrite. For example (assuming `index.php` is the file handling the request), the error document should be set to the desired end result:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=e404
```

Incidentally, you don't necessarily need to explicitly pass the HTTP "error status" (ie. `e404`) in the URL, as this is available in PHP's `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']` superglobal.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

I've assumed you are rewriting to `index.php` (the registered DirectoryIndex)? Instead of falling back to let mod_dir issue an additional subrequest for the DirectoryIndex, you should be explicit and include the file you are rewriting to in the *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

(The `NC` flag is superfluous here.)

> I don't know how to get the wrong URI used before redirecting to `example.com/e404` ...

Stepping back to address your initial query again (as an *academic exercise*). You can do this on Apache 2.4.13+ (although I don't think you *need* to). On Apache 2.4.13+ you can create a dynamic ErrorDocument using Apache expressions.

For example, to explicitly pass the URL-path that caused the 404 error in the URL for the error document itself then you can do something like the following:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?page=%{escape:%{REQUEST_URI}}&error=404
```

The URL param `page` then contains the URL-path (which includes the slash prefix, unlike your rewrite that excludes it). An additional `error` URL param sends the HTTP status (although, as mentioned above, this is not strictly necessary).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think the problem is with the two points you said in the middle of your answer, I will check this (if I will have time) today and will back here, I need to change some parts of my PHP script regarding your answer which make sense for me.

Comment: Okay here we go, first I cannot use your academic exercise which I really like as I have Apache 2.4.6 and not .13+ (I use CentOS and it is not yet available). about the two redirects rounds, you was right, I edited my code with your directive, however, I still get "e404" in database and not the URI before redirect even when I use "$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']" inside my PHP function !

Comment: And just for information, I already have a work around for this problem, I created a jQuery function with an Ajax call which is called when the e404 page loaded, as jQuery is not server side, I can easily get the URI, I don't like this solution but will use it until I find the correct server side solution.

Comment: If you are still getting a second rewrite (although you shouldn't be if you've modified your `ErrorDocument` directive as above) then you'll need to use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP variable to reference the URL that triggered the 404. As mentioned above, if there are two rewrites then `REDIRECT_URL` will contain details of the error document URL (the last "redirect/rewrite").

Comment: Ahhhh, you are right, my mistake, I used : REDIRECT_URL, well I can confirm this is working perfectly now :) Thank you very much.